# How to verify that an address is mine

Tags: tokens, wallets, usdc

I transferred usdc to an ethereum address apparently and now am supposed to verify that the address is indeed mine. I see the amount (token) on etherscan but don't know how to claim it. It's asking me for compiler version and open source license type and I have no idea what these are.  I transferred it off of crypto.com.

Comment: Who told you to verify the address? Due to the question asked it appears you are trying to verify a contract. Is your address a contract? How did you generate that address?

Comment: ok. what I am trying to do is get my monwy out of the system.  I had it in crypto.com and have the "receipt" showing that it got transfered out. it shows it being usdc to usd, but the address it shows it going to is one that i myself got on crypto that was generated for me, or so I thought.  Now the transaction is showing on Etherscan at that address but in order to claim it, I need to get verified, whatever that means.  I just want to get my money out. That's all.

Comment: If you want to get fiat money you need to use an exchange that provides that service and comply their requirements. If you want to move your tokens to your own address then you usually do not need to verify the address.